# Using styled-jsx in published NPM package gives Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `jsx`

Tags: npm, babeljs, next.js, styled-jsx

I’m trying to make an easy-to-use NPM package out of my [nextjs-generic-landing-page](https://github.com/tomsoderlund/nextjs-generic-landing-page) and the NPM is now at https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-generic-landing-page

For some reason, the components using `styled-jsx` do not work, they render weirdly and produce a warning:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `jsx`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: jsx="true" or jsx={value.toString()}.
  in style
  in div
  in SocialSharing (at pages/index.js:32)
  …
```

Here’s the code I use to build the NPM package using Babel:

```
"publish:npm": "rm -rf dist && for folder in {components,lib,config,public}; do mkdir -p dist/${folder} && babel ${folder} -d dist/${folder} --copy-files --presets=@babel/preset-env,next; done && cp package.json dist/"
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the `styled-jsx/babel` plugin:

```
"publish:npm": "rm -rf dist && for folder in {components,lib,config,public}; do mkdir -p dist/${folder} && babel ${folder} -d dist/${folder} --copy-files --presets=@babel/preset-env,next --plugins=styled-jsx/babel; done && cp package.json dist/"
```